# How can make component level variable as constant in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I want to have a component level variable as constant in ReactJS, Redux with Typescript.

```
export class MyComponent {
  initialProps = {};

  constructor() {
  }

componentWillMount() {
  this.initialProps = this.props; //Early tried without this. But this.props is getting changed because of the filter obj.name in the below function.
}

render() {
  return(
    <MyPanel>
     //Another <select> widget 
     {this.getCustomObject()}
    </MyPanel>
  );
}

getCustomObject() {

if(this.props.selectedId == 2) {
let filteredTypes = [];
this.initialProps.obj.forEach((o) => {
  if(this.props.obj.name !== 'ABC'){
     filteredTypes.push(this.props.obj);
   }
});
this.props.types = filteredTypes;
}
  return this.props;
}
```

Note: Actually i want to do re-render the component and display the filtered object based on the dropdown selection. But once we filtered. Next time when we change the dropdown value we are getting the filtered the value in the props.

But we need the props which was passed first time to this componennt and filter the values everytime. SO tried with this.initialProps. But that also getting changed once this.props is updated.

Comment: React props are read-only, `this.props.types = filteredTypes;` will not update props.

Comment: Yes. Every first time i am getting the full expected object in this.props. But after that when render executes next time i am getting the filtered value. But the expectation is the actual full object